# PhpStorm Quick return key on css moves cursor outside of code block

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

So I have an issue that when editing CSS within PhpStorm. I am rather fast to type when doing certain blocks of code. There is a feature enabled which automatically adds a closing curly brace which is great. Except on an occasion if I hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key immediately it will move out.

Expected (| - Where I expect the cursor to go):

```
body {
   |
}
```

What happens 10-20% of the time (| - Where the cursor goes):

```
body {}
|
```

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: when the issue occurs, do you enter the closing brace manually, or just type the opening brace and then hit `Enter`?

Comment: @lena it has an automatic closing brace - So I type the { My cursor is between the curly braces. I then hit enter and expect example 1 from the question

Comment: @lena https://i.imgur.com/3Uyh2FP.gif this is the correct behaviour - But sometimes the enter will cause it to go outside of the code block

Comment: I can only repeat the issue when entering the closing brace manually... If I only type `{` + `Enter`, the caret is placed as expected always

Comment: @lena @Phyore You must be still having the `Shift` key pressed when you are pressing your `Enter` key. `Shift+Enter` will result in such exact behaviour. You can go to the `Settings/Preferences | Keymap`, there is "Find Actions by Shortcut" button next to the local search field -- it will show what actions are assigned to the pressed shortcut. If I'm correct then it will be `Start New Line` action. Just remove such shortcut from there .. and perhaps map it to the same action that standard `Enter` does. See this similar recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64196001/783119

Answer (score 1):

As @LazyOne posted in a comment. This is due to the shift key still being held down. You can remove the setting by searching for `Search New Line`.

Question of similarity: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64196001/783119