# PhpStorm 2020.2: How to get caret to line break after creating a method with braces?

Tags: ide, phpstorm, caret

Before I start, `|` represents the IDE caret.

Now my problem is that when I type the following in PhpStorm:

```
public function __construct() {|
```

it will autocomplete to this (which is fine):

```
public function __construct() {|}
```

But when I hit <kbd>return</kbd>, I'd expect the caret to move like this:

```
public function __construct() {
   |
}
```

But instead it moves like this:

```
public function __construct() {}
|
```

I have hunted in as many code style options and settings as I can but for love nor money can I get this to work!

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: It works like that already for me (PhpStorm 2020.2.2 x64 on Windows 10). 1) Try disabling all custom (not bundled by default) plugins and see if it will make any difference 2) Try switching back to the Default keymap for your OS 3) Show you settings (`Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Smart keys` in particular). 4) Check for any relevant exceptions in the `idea.log` file (Help | Show Log in XXX).

Comment: So far for me it sounds like instead of making an actual new line .. it just moves caret to the next line. Here on Windows 10 and Default (Windows-based) keymap I can reproduce the same "move" by pressing `Shift + Enter` which corresponds to "Start New Line" action (or Ctrl+Shift+Enter which is different action). Go to `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` -- there is "Find Actions by Shortcut" button next to the local search field -- see what actions it will return when you hist `Enter` or the actual shortcut for the aforementioned action...

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment, friend. You were right in that I needed to resolve the issue at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Smart keys`. For some bizarre reason, I had to uncheck the "End on blank line moves caret to indent position" and hit apply then all worked again

Answer (score 1):

@LazyOne has helped me resolve this issue by prompting me to check Keymap.

I realised when I was typing (too fast and clumsy) my finger was still pressing `Shift+Enter` which triggered the `Start New Line` keymap.

I had to remove this mapping and additionally map `Shift+Enter` to the Editors' `Enter` keymap.